# Maintaining multiple connection pools with spring/eclipse link

Tags: spring, jpa, transactions, eclipselink, spring-transactions

we use spring and eclipse link (using the eclipse link connection pool)
We'd like to allocate two connection pools- the default should be used normally, the second should be used for transactional methods that requires a new transaction (@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW))

is it possible?
thanks..

Comment: Sure.  If you are using EclipseLink internal pools as described here: http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/concepts/data_access006.htm you would configure the default and read pool as described here http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/p_connection_pool.htm and here http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/p_connection_pool_read.htm#CHDDIIFD

Comment: thanks, but how do i connect between the pools and spring? i'd like spring to use the second pool only when entering a REQUIRES_NEW transactional method - i only see 'read' in the link you provided, but i refer to a standard transaction which is read write

Comment: If Spring is handling transactions, it needs to handle the datasources as well, so you can't use an Eclipselink connection pool.  You instead need to define transactional and non-transactional datasources with the jta-data-source and non-jta-data-source tags in the persistence.xml.  Spring configuration will inject these into the persistence context for you though.  The only example I have handy is https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/JPASpring

Comment: i don't want to use non transactional data source, i just want to have a dedicated pool for the requires_new. currently we use spring with it's transaction manager (aspects) with eclipse link default pool. the question is whether i can get in between spring and eclipse link to force it to use another pool if entering a REQUIRES_NEW transaction

Comment: JPA just gets a connection from the transactional pool when it is in a transaction and has no knowledge of the transactional boundary types.  So you would need to define a different persistence unit for the methods with the Requires_NEW transactional boundaries to use, and configure your methods to use this persistence unit instead.  I don't know of any spring configuration that would handle it for you

Comment: ok, thanks. (apparently i am required to enter a long enough answer lol. didnt figure out that)